# mailchimp repeatable area dropping image and replacing with HTML anchor link

Tags: html, tags, mailchimp, newsletter

We designed a custom HTML template for mailchimp and it works fine if I don’t have any repeatable areas, but there is one area we need to be repeatable where we can showcase featured projects for the past month. The problem seems to be when we try to make this single repeatable  area it looks fine in the campaign edit window with the images appearing (either via uploading into our library or selecting those already there) but when we then go to Preview the newsletter the images in the repeatable area are removed and an anchor tag appears instead. I thought it was because of DIV names repeating but checked the code and they are all unique from what I found. Mailchimp support could also not offer any thoughts on the problem. have attached some screen captures and the full HTML below so you can see. Any suggestions you could give would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code we are using:

http://www.ashantieaton.com/mailchimp/ae_custom_template.html

And here are screen captures showing the problem:

http://www.ashantieaton.com/mailchimp/preview_showing_bug.png

Comment: http://www.ashantieaton.com/mailchimp/nonrepeatable_area_preview.png
http://www.ashantieaton.com/mailchimp/repeatable_area_unfilled.png

Comment: Those links above show how it looks when we don't make the area repeatable and how it looks when we do, and are just looking at the content edit window.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was simply solved. It was just due to a mailchimp bug and when the code was copied from Komodo Edit, the software used to edit the HTML, and then back into a fresh custom template form in mailchimp the repeatable area worked as intended.